# Installing iOS certificates locally

Tags: ios, xcode

On the Apple site, in the Certificates section, I see that I have two certificates (iOS Development and iOS Distribution). They both expire in 2017. Everything looks fine there.

When I download the certificates and try to install them locally, they both appear in the “Certificates” section of my Keychain. In the “My certificates” section of my Keychain, however, I see only the Developer certificate. If I try to copy the Distribution certificate from “Certificates” to “My Certificates”, it does not help.

In XCode, in the Accounts section, when I choose my Apple ID and click on “View Details,” I see only “iOS Development” in the list of Signing Identities. And its status is “Revoked” for some reasons! When I click on “+” under the table and try to add iOS Distribution certificate, a dialog appears which says: “Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate. You have a valid iOS Distribution certificate in the Member Center, but it is not installed locally. If your signing identity is installed on another Mac, you can export a developer profile on that Mac and import it on this Mac. You can also revoke your current certificate and request a new one.”

Is it safe to go to the Apple site and revoke the certificates there? Would it help somehow? Or maybe there are better solutions?

Comment: Yes, you need to revoke that both certificate from the apple site and then install it. It will work..!

Answer (score 2):

You may revoke your distribution and create a new one with CertificateSigningRequest created from keychain access. But if you have other project using this distribution certificate, It is better export that certificate from the originally installed computer using keychain access export with the .p12 extension and install it to your computer.

If you export a certificate distribution or development. You need to go to [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) and renew all your previous provisioning file with a new certificate. It is time consuming but if you are not able to export old certificate that is the only option.

Comment: How do you actually do this?

Comment: How do you actually do what. Can you be more specific ?